# Indirect countif only working for the first sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a question about a Google Sheet I am working in. The sheet has multiple tabs per person who put their predictions for a winning team. I want to calculate how often a value has been inputted, across all the sheets.

However, when I try my solution, it only checks for the first sheet, not the others.

Here is my formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & I2:I43 & "'!A2"),C2))
```

In this:

- I2:I43 is a list of all my sheets.
- A2 is the location on all sheets that I want to check
- C2 is my target value that I want to count.

I have also tried to put this as an array formula like so:

```
=ArrayFormula((SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & I2:I6 & "'!A2"),C2))))
```

This also does not work.

I would like to avoid Google Apps Script as this formula has to be done on multiple spots through out the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the purpose of SUM in your formula, but try something like this:

```
=MAP(I2:I43,LAMBDA(tab,COUNTIF(INDIRECT(tab&"!A2"),C2)))
```

Comment: NIce.  The purpose of `SUM` is to get the total number of times the value appears across all sheets.  Preface the answer above with `SUM` if only the total number of times is desired.  For example: `=SUM(MAP(I2:I43,LAMBDA(tab,COUNTIF(INDIRECT(tab&"!A2"),C2))))`.  Otherwise, leave as is to indicate which sheets have matching values.

Comment: Hi Z.

Thank you for the formula! This works flawlessly. I have added the SUM back since I want to get the total of right predictions in a single cell.